# Express Node JS

Tags: node.js, express

Following is my code as follows:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

app.route('/user')
    .get(function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello' + req.params.id);
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

It runs fine with http://localhost:8000/ but with http://localhost:8000/user?id=D it gives following error: Cannot GET /user?id=D.

WHat is wrong in my code? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try accessing http://localhost:8000/user/D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route syntax:

```
'/user/:id'
```

matches a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/user/4095
```

---

If you use a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/user?id=D
```

then, you will need to use a `"/user"` route and read the query parameter for the `id` value from `req.query.id` as described [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query).

---

In addition, your don't need the `app.route()` as it's just an extra level of complication for things you are not doing here. I'd suggest this simplification which I have tested and works:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello: ' + req.query.id);
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated code above. It still doesnt work. The output this time is : Helloundefined.

Comment: @DevD - two more changes recommended in my answer now.  I tested the code in my answer and it works.